# Event ID 4723 - An attempt was made to change an account's password. + Event ID 4625

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, user-accounts, event-viewer

I was going through Event Viewer to track down a software issue and came across these security logs:

Event ID 4723
An attempt was made to change an account's password.

```
Subject:
  Security ID:   SYSTEM
  Account Name:   DESKTOP-AAAAAAA$
  Account Domain:   WWWWWW
  Logon ID:   0x3E7

Target Account:
  Security ID:   DESKTOP-AAAAAAA\Administrator
  Account Name:   Administrator
  Account Domain:   DESKTOP-AAAAAAA

Additional Information:
  Privileges   -
```

XML:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{000000-000-00000-00000-000000000}" /> 
  <EventID>4723</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>13824</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-08-26T17:06:55.7385645Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>21161</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{******-****-*****-****-******701}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1124" ThreadID="1172" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-AAAAAAA</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
<EventData>
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">DefaultAccount</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetDomainName">DESKTOP-AAAAAA</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetSid">S-1-5-21-00000000-00000000-0000000-503</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">DESKTOP-AAAAAAA$</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">WWWWWW</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data> 
  <Data Name="PrivilegeList">-</Data> 
 </EventData>
 </Event>
```

Followed by
Event ID 4625
An account failed to log on.

```
Subject:
  Security ID:   SYSTEM
  Account Name:   DESKTOP-AAAAAAA$
  Account Domain:   WWWWWW
  Logon ID:   0x3E7

Logon Type:     2

Account For Which Logon Failed:
  Security ID:   NULL SID
  Account Name:   Administrator
  Account Domain:   DESKTOP-AAAAAAA

Failure Information:
  Failure Reason:   Account currently disabled.
  Status:     0xC000006E
  Sub Status:   0xC0000072

Process Information:
  Caller Process ID: 0x464
  Caller Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe

Network Information:
  Workstation Name: DESKTOP-AAAAAAA
  Source Network Address: -
  Source Port:   -

Detailed Authentication Information:
  Logon Process:   Advapi
  Authentication Package: Negotiate
  Transited Services: -
  Package Name (NTLM only): -
  Key Length:   0
```

XML:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{000000-000-00000-00000-000000000}" /> 
  <EventID>4625</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12544</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-08-26T17:06:55.7411056Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>21162</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{******-****-*****-****-******701}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1124" ThreadID="1212" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-AAAAAAA</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>

 <EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">DESKTOP-AAAAAAA$</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">WWWWWW</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">DefaultAccount</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetDomainName">DESKTOP-AAAAAAA</Data> 
  <Data Name="Status">0xc000006e</Data> 
  <Data Name="FailureReason">%%2310</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubStatus">0xc0000072</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonType">2</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonProcessName">Advapi</Data> 
  <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">Negotiate</Data> 
  <Data Name="WorkstationName">DESKTOP-AAAAAAA</Data> 
  <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="LmPackageName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="KeyLength">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessId">0x464</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessName">C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">-</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

There are some for the  Administrator account, and some for the DefaultAccount a couple today, more from a week a go. Some are on consecutive days.
Is this something I should be worried about?
Is someone trying to access my PC/hack into an administrator account?
What triggers these logs?
I have not been trying to change any password.
I'm on a local account(disabled all Microsoft account settings after activation).
Antivirus has always been enabled (Bitdefender).
Scanned with Windows Security, Bitdefender, Malwarebytes - all clean.
Windows 10 Pro/Home (latest updates, Bitdefender Internet Security, local account)- it seems to be happening on both my computers.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a web server (IIS) on the computer? Please include in your post the entire XML data from the Event Viewer for events 4723 and 4625.

Comment: No I don't have an IIS server... at least I didn't install one. It's my personal computer, with a 2 week fresh windows installation.

Comment: I'll get the XMLs up shortly, I need to get back to the home. Thanks.

Comment: @harrymc I've added the xml's, edited some non relevant values. Tell me if they are relevant and i'll add them back.  I copied the wrong ones... these are for the DefaultAccount, but the ones for the Administator are the same only different user name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the System IDs (SID) that are used in the XML, these events are
initiated from your computer by installed software or system service.

It's possible that these were issued by your antivirus checking out
your security settings, but more digging could be useful.

It could also come from some process trying to impersonate the
Administrator account and gain super-privileges.
This possibility is worrisome.

**Event 4625** comes from
[C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Security_Authority_Subsystem_Service)
which is a legitimate and essential Windows component dealing with
security and authenticating.

The "Logon Type" is `2`, which means interactive logon.
It's extremely puzzling why would anyone try to login to your computer
as the built-in Administrator account (which is disabled).
I hope that your computer is not open to the internet.
However, this is less worrying, since `lsass.exe` is heavily protected.

**Event 4723** is more worrisome and the information about its originator
only specifies the process number, but too late to find more info:

```
<Execution ProcessID="1124" ThreadID="1172" />
```

**Suggestion**

I would suggest to try and trap at least event 4723 while it's happening.

In the Event Viewer, you may right-click the event and select
"Attach Task To This Event", with the action of
"Display a message (deprecated)".

Once the message is displayed, you could in Event Viewer find the
Process ID, then find in Task Manager the process that caused the event.
If Task Manager does not give enough info, use the better
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

---

**Conclusion/Opinion**

Both these events are generated by `lsass.exe`, about which
I'm not that worried.

I believe that this is Bitdefender doing an audit of the computer,
and you could verify it by disabling it temporarily.
Windows Defender is now just about as good as any other antivirus,
and is certainly better integrated into Windows.

If you would like more peace of mind, you could deep scan with
more well-known antivirus products, such as
[Kaspersky](https://usa.kaspersky.com/free-antivirus).

I would say that your computer is not infected.

Comment: I couldn't attach the action. It said it's deprecated(going to try again). But I found the process with the ID 1124, the event triggered just now. It's Local Security Authority Process.

Comment: Looks good - I added a conclusion.

Comment: Hope this is Bitdefender, I've check with a friend that has it installed and he sees the same event. If someone else reads this and has Bitdefender installed, check your logs and leave a comment so we confirm this for others looking for an answer to this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone else ending up here, I can confirm that these two Event Log entries 4723 followed by 4625, are indeed caused by Bitdefender. Why I do not know.

However, I have recently started using Bitdefender and have just noticed this behaviour, which concerned me.  As a diagnostic, I uninstalled Bitdefender and yes, the problem goes away.

I should add, the audit entries were still occurring after I uninstalled Bitdefender itself. However there were 2 other Bitdefender programs listed in Programs and Features: Bitdefender VPN and Bitdefender Agent. I subsequently uninstalled both of these, and then the audit failure and password change attempts stopped. Which of these two was causing it, I am not sure - I uninstalled them one after another.

I await comment from Bitdefender as to why these problems occur.

EDIT: As a final diagnostic, I reinstalled Bitdefender an the problem comes back. So these two events are definitely caused by Bitdefender. Whether this is expected behaviour, or a bug, I don't know.

BTW, this is with Windows 11 Pro, Version 21H2, OS Build 22000.593

EDIT2: Finally, to close this subject, Bitdefender have confirmed that this is normal behaviour and is simply caused by Bitdefender Agent checking that a password is set.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1117326)